# How to remove multiple characters from file names under sub dir using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash

Whats best method to remove special charters (multiple characters) from file name
currently I am doing this way but its not efficient to remove multiple different characters at same time eg %$^&* etc

```
import os
"""
Remove () and empty space from file names
"""
path = '/var/www/POD/2021/09/12'
os.chdir(path)

files = os.listdir(path)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        cwd = os.path.join(root, f[:0])
        cwd = os.chdir(cwd)
        os.rename(f, f.replace(' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

This look like task for `.translate` method, consider following example

```
name = "name (with )brackets"
remove = "( )"
t = str.maketrans("", "", remove)
new_name = name.translate(t)
print(new_name)
```

output

```
namewithbrackets
```

Explanation: `.maketrans` takes 2 or 3 arguments, first 2 must be equal-length `str`s, n-th character from first is replace with corresponding character from second. I do not use this features, so I put empty `str`, third argument is str with characters to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this is how I manage to implement

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test'
os.chdir(path)
remove = "(  )"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    t = str.maketrans("", "", remove)
    newname = filename.translate(t)
    os.rename(filename, newname)
```